# Assigning Value of a formula to a cell

Tags: function, vba, excel-2007, formula

I have a data chart with many products.

I want to filter each type of product, calculate the total quantity of that type as well as the number of product inside that type. And finally put the **value** of that function into a column in Sheet 2.

Here is the code. The quantity column is column U. It gets error 1004: Argument not optional, and it highlights the Set .... = FunctionR1C1 = .... part

```
Function T_Quantity()
    ActiveSheet.Range("U").Select
    Total = FunctionR1C1 = "=subtotal(9,C[0])"
End Function

Function T_Count(ref_column)
    ActiveSheet.Range("U").Select
    Total = FunctionR1C1 = "=subtotal(2,C[0])"
End Function

Sub Total_Count()
Dim my_array() As String
Dim iLoop As Integer
Dim iCount As Integer

iCount = 1
ReDim my_array(3)

my_array(0) = "=M1747B"
my_array(1) = "=M1747C"
my_array(2) = "=M1766B"

For iLoop = LBound(my_array) To UBound(my_array)

    ActiveSheet.Range("A:BB").Select

    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=my_array
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Calculate the quantity and no of lot, put in colum A,B in sheet 2'
    Set Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCount, 1) = T_Quantity()
    Set Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCount, 2) = T_Count()
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    iCount = iCount + 1

Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: You're not passing any arguments to the functions; your functions are not returning any value(s) and as such, you're using a function when you could/should be using a `Sub`. Also, `Total = FunctionR1C1 = "=subtotal(9,C[0])"` is nonsense, it's a boolean expression (at best) which will return only a `True` or `False`.

Comment: Yeah, I am a begginer, so my knowledge is a bit limited :"> But I thought when you need to return a value then you need to use a function insted of a sub And one more thing, I am not sure about assigning formula also, can you rewrite the fucntion for me, I just want to assign the "value" of the function to a variable or to pass down to one cell. THanks

Comment: Yes and no. You should use a function to *calculate* and return a value to the subroutine, if you're simply manipulating the worksheet object -- which you are doing -- this can be part of your existing subroutine, or it could be another subroutine.  I'll try to give you a suggestion.

Comment: May I ask why you are using VBA to do this? Are you aware of the out of the box functionalities to summarize, slice and dice data, like Pivot tables? If so, fine, get on with your project, but I just wanted to make sure you're not spending months on coding something that can be achieved with a few clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with this and see if that gets you any closer to your desired results:

```
Sub Total_Count()
Dim my_array() As String
Dim iLoop As Integer
Dim iCount As Integer

iCount = 1

ReDim my_array(3)
my_array(0) = "=M1747B"
my_array(1) = "=M1747C"
my_array(2) = "=M1766B"

For iLoop = LBound(my_array) To UBound(my_array)
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:BB").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=my_array
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Calculate the quantity and no of lot, put in colum A,B in sheet 2'
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCount, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=subtotal(9,C[0])"
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iCount, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=subtotal(2,C[0])"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    iCount = iCount + 1

Next iLoop

End Sub
```

What I changed:

- Eliminate the `Set` keyword when working with cell objects on the Worksheet.  `Set` is used to assign object variables.
- Since the functions you call appear to be simply setting the cell's `FormulaR1C1` property, I add the `.FormulaR1C1` property to those lines, and then, instead of using a `Function`, I simply put the function's R1C1 notation directly in this subroutine.

Comment: Thanks, my code right now is actually quite the same, I just paste value of those column (with formula to another column in another sheet since (I am not very farmiliar with reference yet :) Thank your help